# Not able to run scenario while using cucumber-jvm with selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver, cucumber, automated-tests, cucumber-junit, cucumber-java

```
specification
|-src
  |-test
    |-java
      |-MyFeature1
        |-MyFeature1Steps.java 
        |-MyFeature1Test.java
      |-MyFeature2
        |-MyFeature2Steps.java 
        |-MyFeature2Test.java
    |-resources
      |-Features
        |-MyFeature1
          |-MyFeature1.feature
        |-MyFeature2
          |-MyFeature2.feature
```

In `MyFeature1Test.java` , I have this:

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(format = { "pretty", "html:target/cucumber", "json:target/cucumber.json" }, features = "classpath:Features" , tags = "@registration", glue={"classpath:MyFeature1/MyFeature1Steps.java"})

public class MyFeature1Test
{   
}
```

Scenario File `MyFeature1.feature`:

```
@registration
Feature: Login and Registration tests

   Background: 
   Given User is on Sign In Page

   # 1 Register using Username and password
   Scenario Outline: 
      Given User clicks on Sign Up
      And User fills the details
      When User provides "new" email
      And User activates the account
      And Configures password
      Then User should be registered
```

My `pom.xml` is as follows:

```
   <dependency>
     <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
     <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
     <version>1.1.8</version>
     <scope>test</scope>
   </dependency>

    <dependency>
       <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
       <artifactId>cucumber-core</artifactId>
       <version>1.1.8</version>
       <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

     <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.8</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-jvm-deps</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.3</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-picocontainer</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>gherkin</artifactId>
        <version>2.12.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.11</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

When I run the runner file using maven , I always get result as:

```
Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 1.641 sec - in TestSuite

Results :

Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
```

Running through Eclipse also show me output as:

```
@registration
Feature: Login and Registration tests

0 Scenarios
0 Steps
0m0.000s
```

What am I doing wrong here as I am able to run `MyFeature2.feature` in same structure successfully.

Answer (score 2):

I can see few potential issues here:

1. `glue` parameter should point to a Java package, not directory. So something like `glue = {"com.test.functional.gluecode..."}`
2. Your scenario is not defined correctly. `Scenario Outline` is used when you want to create multiple repetitive scenarios while providing input data for each scenario in `Examples` table. For example:

.

```
  Scenario Outline: eating
  Given there are <start> cucumbers
  When I eat <eat> cucumbers
  Then I should have <left> cucumbers

  Examples:
    | start | eat | left |
    |  12   |  5  |  7   |
    |  20   |  5  |  15  |
```

In your case, change it to just `Scenario`.

Comment: Replacing Scenario Outline with Scenario, worked like a charm. Thanks !!

Comment: @MonikaKhandelwal Great! Please accept the answer if it helped you.

Answer (score 0):

change scenario outline in your feature file to scenario

point glue parameter to step defination package